# ReactJS - Recursive method for nested elements using ES6 generators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, generator

In a React app, in order to loop through **nested arrays**, I am using a method like this:

```
recursiveMethod = () => {
 // some code... 
this.recursiveMethod();
}
```

However, I think it doesn't look good and I want to use ES6 generators instead.

something like :

```
function* genFunc() {
  ...
  yield; 
  ...
}
```

but I am not sure about how the code style should look like. I need a function which I can use in other methods. for example, the function which returns an array at the end. I want to call the function in other method like render(){...} and get the result array.

**Update 1:**
I have some other values in the nested array which I want to get as the output. Is it ok if I use yield two times in the same block? I mean in the else{} block of the code below:

```
if (condition) {
      yield element;
    } else {
      yield element;
      yield* traverseNested(element);
    }
```

**Update 2**
By the other values I mean:

```
[{
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2,
   key3: { iterMe : {
            otherKey: otherValue,
            otherKey: otherValue,
            iterMe : { iterMe : {...} }}
    }
   },{},{},{}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by other values? Please add an example. And yes you can have multiple yield statements in the same block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this for **nested arrays**, I too am experimenting with these. So, please test it thoroughly.

- First check if the data is present or not
- Now, loop through the array
- If you encounter anything other than an array, then yield the value
- Else yield the function with the subset of data, similar to a recursive function

Works with React as well [**WORKING DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xwpe4v)

**NOTE:** This traverses the nested array in a Depth first fashion.

```js
const k = [10, [20], [[1, [2, 3, 4]]]];

function* traverseNested(data){
  if (!data) { return; }

  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var element = data[i];

    element instanceof Array 
     ?
     yield* traverseNested(element)
     : 
     yield element    
  }
}

let iter = traverseNested(k);
let res = iter.next()

while(!res.done){
  console.log(res.value);
  res = iter.next();
}

// Or this for .. of iterator can also be used
// for (let res of iter) { 
//   console.log(res); 
// }
```

Comment: Once you've assigned your generator to the `iter` variable, you can even do a `for (res of iter) { console.log(res.value); }` instead of iterating manually with `next()`

Comment: Thank you, I added that as well into the snippet. But it has to be `for (res of iter) { console.log(res); }` no need for res.value().

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! Copied over your inner statement without giving it enough thought :D

Comment: Thanks Nandu, since my original question has edited by other users, I have to mention, I want this method in a ReactJS component, I am using ES6 in ReactJS but I don't know how to use the "function* traverseNested(data){...}" in the ReactJS ecosystem, I am using a linter which does not accept the code. I need a method (function) which can be used in other parts of my component (for example in render() method). Regards.

Comment: I don't know which linter you are using but it works in a React application just fine. I am attaching a link to StackBlitz that has the working app. Please check it out.